# How to set computing device to CUDA once for all in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I am using CUDA for my neural network training using Pytorch.

Every time I create tensor for computing I need to explicitly allocate it to CUDA either by `device="CUDA"` or by `.to("CUDA")`. It is very annoying and is there a way to set the default computation device to CUDA so that I dont have to do it manually each time? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make a class for your neural network, inherit it from `torch.nn.Module`, you can move the whole object of your neural network `.to("cuda")`, then all weights stored as fields of this class will be also on CUDA. If you use some custom parameter tensors, you'll need to register them as `torch.nn.Parameter`. You'll now only have to manually move your data batches to CUDA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the default tensor type to a cuda tensor.

```py
torch.set_default_tensor_type("torch.cuda.FloatTensor")
```